# How to use ChromeView without chrome application in device

Tags: android, chromeview

I'm now having problem that I'm using ChromeView in my application. All are working smooth if device has chrome application. Problem is got error occurring without chrome application in device. Any suggest?

Library is from https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview

Answer (score 0):

ChromeView's Deprecation Notice saied that The recommended alternative is the Crosswalk Project.you can get it at [corsswalk-project](https://crosswalk-project.org/).